# Storing a reversed string

Tags: java

I Want to store the reversed string a in b without any function.

> public static void main(String args[])
>     {
>
> ```
>   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
>   String a=br.readLine();
>   String b;
>   for(int x=0,y=a.length()-1;x<a.length();x++,y--)
>   {
>              b.charAt(x)=a.charAt(y);
>   }
> ```

But I get this error :

> ```
>                    b.charAt(x)=a.charAt(y);
>                            ^
> ```
>
> required: variable
>
> found:    value
>
> 1 error

Can you explain it and help me fix it ?

Comment: You can *only* assign to l-values ("left-hand values"). In Java this is restricted to *variables*. `f("foo") = "bar";` is always invalid in Java as `f("foo")` is an expression (invoking a method) and not a variable, which is required .. as the error states. (Array indexes are also variables in the Java sense, which is why an array of char, `char[]`, allows, `charArr[index] = 'x';`)

Comment: "_Please solve the error_". No, thanks.

Comment: @Baz. Was it a bad day for you? yeah? haha :)

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, didn't mean to be rude :D

Comment: @Baz. AH its ok. Just nitpicking. As I saw one more similar comment of yours in a question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do

```
String a = "hello"; // the String to be reversed
String b = ""; // the String to store the reversed String
for (int i = a.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    b = b+a.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Left to the = sign, you must have a variable name, not an expression.

But you can't do it like this, because a string is immutable : you should use another structure than a string, for example a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), which is especially designed to allow efficient appending for string building :

```
  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  for(int x=0,y=a.length()-1;x<a.length();x++,y--) {
         b.append(a.charAt(y));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to reverse a string is to use a String Buffer since it has a built in reverse method. Then to store the String buffer you can save it to a variable like this.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a.reverse());

sb.toString(); //if you want the result as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `b` in the beginning as : `String b = "";`

and then simply replace

```
b.charAt(x)=a.charAt(y);
```

with

```
 b= b+ a.charAt(y);
```

This will append the characters in `b`

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse it's char array as follows:

```
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

for(int i=0; i<chars.length/2; i++) {
    char temp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[chars.length - i - 1];
    chars[chars.length - i - 1] = temp;
}

String reversed = String.valueOf(chars);
```

But note that no matter what you choose, you won't be modifying the string itself because string is immutable as @dystroy suggested.